# Can't add events to inline SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to access inline SVG elements in JavaScript, to add a click event. I'm running into issues adding the event to anything else than a single element identified with id.
Using document.getElementById("p1_1_1") will work, but I'll need to manipulate 200 rectangles, so I will need to use document.getElementsByTagName or document.getElementsByClassName - both of which return meaningful HTMLCollections, but the addEvent won't add the event.

I've tried Firefox 17 and Chrome 23, and some additional methods, such as the `getElementsByTagNameNS`, bu no luck so far.

Thankful for any help you can offer.

Here are stripped down versions of the JS code and HTML/SVG I'm working with:

**JavaScript:**

```
 function testing() {
    var testDiv = document.getElementById("tester");
    testDiv.innerHTML = '<h1>Success!</h1><br>';
}

function addEvent(obj, evt, func) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, func, false)
    } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, func);
    } else {
        alert("no success adding event");
    }
}

function init() {
    var targetSquares = document.getElementsByTagName("rect");
    addEvent(targetSquares, "click", testing);
}

window.addEvent(window, "load", init);
```

**inline SVG**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bsroyale.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="tester">
</div>
        <div id="gamemap">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                   viewBox="0 0 600 600">
                <rect x="50" y="50" width="20" height="20" class="p1" id="p1_1_1" />
                <rect x="71" y="50" width="20" height="20" class="p1" id="p1_2_1" />
                <rect x="92" y="50" width="20" height="20" class="p1" id="p1_3_1" />
                <rect x="113" y="50" width="20" height="20" class="p1" id="p1_4_1" />
                <rect x="134" y="50" width="20" height="20" class="p1" id="p1_5_1" />
                <!-- etc etc, 200 rect in total-->
            </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("rect")` returns an HTML collection. You must then loop through this collection (i.e. for each...) and add the event listeners to each collection-item.

I didn't test it, but your init function could look like this:

```
function init() {
    var targetSquares = document.getElementsByTagName("rect");
    for (var i = 0; i < targetSquares.length; i++) {
        addEvent(targetSquares[i], "click", testing);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `var rect = document.querySelector('rect');` for a single, or `var rects = document.querySelectorall('rect');` for a collection.